# GSON pretty priniting doesn't support indentation?

Tags: gson, pretty-print

Taken from javadoc of GSON.setPrettyPrinting :
"Configures Gson to output Json that fits in a page for pretty printing."

Ok, fitting to a page is nice. But I want it to be human readable.

and instead:

```
{"key":"smartphones","solutions":[{"id":"0 ","name":"LG Nexus"}]}
```

have:

```
{
"key" : "smartphones",
"solutions" : [{
        "id" : "0 ",
        "name" : "LG Nexus 5"
        }]
}
```

**--UPDATE --**

PrettyPrinting works as expected for latest version (2.2.4).
Unfortunately, the code I used to test the question was of version 1.4, which I have to use :(

Comment: Can you show how you are using it?

Comment: Can you add the full listing to the question, instead of including it in the comments? Secondly, what happens if you register the type adapters first? I know the spec says it shouldn't matter, I am just curious.

Comment: Also what happens if you add the 'enableComplexMapKeySerialization' to the builder chain?